# Make XMLWriter to append data to an existing file

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

Is there any way to make XMLWriter to append data to an existing file?

Comment: Why are you trying to append XML to a file? Are you sure this is the exact behavior you need? Remember that you cannot just "append" to an XML file or you'll break the structure making it invalid!

Comment: @redShadow: I need to append because I'm running a long-processing PHP script that eats memory because of memory leaks, so I have to split the process through a bash script. This means I have to write the XML file in chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`openMemory`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-open-memory.php) to create an XMLWriter that only writes to memory, then [`outputMemory`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-output-memory.php) to get the data that the XMLWriter has collected, and then append it to a file with normal `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose` calls.

Comment: I can't use memory as I'm calling different PHP processes from a bash shell script. So I need to deal with an existing file... but I'm seeing it's not possible :( EDIT: Oh now I understand your comment, I'll try.